# implement a searchfield

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need to implement a search field and I need that it is exactly the same like the one in the right-high corner http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#

for now i do:

```
//called on key up
onSearchQueryChanged: function(field) {
var queryString = field.getValue();

    var store = Ext.getStore('Customers');
store.clearFilter();

if(queryString){
    var thisRegEx = new RegExp(queryString, "i");
    store.filterBy(function(record) {
            if (thisRegEx.test(record.get('name')) || thisRegEx.test(record.get('code')))   
            return true;
            };
        return false;
    });
    }
},

//clearicontap
onSearchReset: function(field, b, c) {
var store = Ext.getStore('Customers');
    store.clearFilter();
field.setValue('Search');
},

//focus
onMouseOn: function(field, b, c) {
field.setValue('');
},
```

the search work fine.. the only problem is that when I clear the field pressing the clear icon tap the field remain empty… but i want to re-write 'Search', like you can see in the onSearchReset function….

there is a solution? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using xtype `searchfield` then just apply [`placeHolder`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Search-cfg-placeHolder) config. Even if you are not using `xtype:searchfield` then also you can use `placeHolder` . You don't need to manually set it back to default value.

```
xtype: 'searchfield',
label: 'Query',
placeHolder:'Search',
name: 'query'
```